# WooCommerce product stock resets to 0

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

First I'd like to note that I'm somewhat new to WooCommerce and this site was not built by me.

The problem is as follows. I add a product --> set certain stock amount  --> after some random time (usually after half an hour, sometimes many hours) the product suddenly goes out of stock. This happens both with single products and variation products and in both the Woo backend and frontend. This issue does not affect products that were added at earlier times, only new products.

The site uses Flatsome child theme, it was built probably 3-4 years ago. Some of the child theme files show messages they need updating. However, I can't really update them without breaking the site. So I'm wondering if these files can affect the "product goes out of stock by itself" problem?

```
archive-product.php version 3.3.0 is out of date. The core version is 3.4.0,
thankyou.php version 3.2.0 is out of date. The core version is 3.7.0,
content-single-product.php version 3.0.0 is out of date. The core version is 3.6.0,
rating.php version 2.3.2 is out of date. The core version is 3.6.0,
review-meta.php version 3.0.0 is out of date. The core version is 3.4.0,
tabs.php version 2.4.0 is out of date. The core version is 3.8.0,
single-product-reviews.php version 2.3.2 is out of date. The core version is 4.3.0,
content-product_cat.php version 2.6.1 is out of date. The core version is 4.7.0
```

All plugins are up do date.

What I've tried:

- Tested by creating many new products.
- Turned the "manage stock" off and back on.
- I've Increased PHP memory limit.
- Regenerated product lookup tables

Any ideas why the products go out of stock?

Comment: Your website has a problem. Disable every plugins instead of WoOCommerce and find out which plugin produces this problem. Never had this before with this theme.

Comment: "the product suddenly goes out of stock". The status changes to Out of stock or the stock number goes to 0?. is there any "cronjob" working at the background?

Comment: In the frontend, the status changes to out of stock and in the backend it's just goes to 0. Not sure about the cronjobs, there are a few running but I've no idea if they're the cuplrit here.